# ros workspace file system?

Tags: ros, filesystem

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can your ros_workspace folder be located on an NTFS file system?

I'm using ros electric and a wubi install of ubuntu 11.10.

I've added a new hard drive that I want both windows and linux to access, and I'd like to move my ros_workspace folder to the new hard drive. Unfortunately when I run my nodes from the new environment I get:

$ rosrun loader_testing boomPosCnt

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named boomPosCnt below /media/may2013/ros_workspace/loader_testing
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /media/may2013/ros_workspace/loader_testing/bin/boomPosCnt

When I switch the environment back to the old workspace in my home folder (ext4 file system) the nodes run fine. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63952/ros-workspace-file-system?/) by [4praytor](https://answers.ros.org/users/5019/4praytor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [4praytor](https://answers.ros.org/users/5019/4praytor/) on 2013-05-30**:
Thanks mirzashah your idea worked!

I wound up following this post to remount the drive: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1604251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the problem lies in the fact that NTFS does not follow Unix file system permission conventions (read/write/executable), in particular the concept of executable permissions.

When you try to run the node "boomPosCnt", it does not have execute permissions.

There is a workaround in the following thread which involves mounting the NTFS partition in a way that gives execute permissions...it may help with your problem:

http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=65473

---

Originally posted by [mirzashah](https://answers.ros.org/users/3576/mirzashah/) with karma: 1209 on 2013-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-05-30**:
@4praytor Please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left.